# Python Pexpect issue : Getting prompt between the command and result

Tags: python, linux, pexpect

I can see that this is not a Python/Pexpect issue but way two Linux machines communicate with each other.

But will appreciate if someone can help me find a way to handle this.

i issue the command and then expect for the prompt , get the Before and look for what i need(response) and then i move on to next command.

what is happening is that i see that after i issue a command in the before i get the command and then command prompt.

```
cmd = 'rm /usr/local/file'
self.myobj.sendline(cmd)
match = self.myobj.expect(self.prompts, timeout=timeout)
print self.dut_host.before
print self.dut_host.after
```

if i do it manually i will be getting something like

```
MYPROMPT> rm /usr/local/file

rm: cannot remove '/usr/local/file': No such file or directory
```

But what gets printed is

```
MYPROMPT> rm /usr/local/file  <-- self.dut_host.before
MYPROMPT>                     <--- self.dut_host.after
```

and the actual output i will see in the next command and eventually killing my program.

Has anybody faced this issue and can anybody suggest a way i can tackle this.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: see whether it relates to [the timing issue](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/commonissues.html#timing-issue-with-send-and-sendline), try to increase `delaybeforesend`. To run commands via ssh, consider [fabric](http://fabfile.org). Here's [code example](http://ideone.com/3Fzw09)

Comment: i tried several of delaybeforesend values but no help :(

Answer (score 0):

change the code like this:

```
cmd = 'rm /usr/local/file'
self.myobj.sendline(cmd)
print self.dut_host.before
print self.dut_host.after
match = self.myobj.expect(self.prompts, timeout=timeout)
```